# Three threads involved in calling an async method

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I am investigating async, and I have come across the following result which I cannot explain.

The following code (which can be copy/pasted into Linqpad or similar) gives the, to me, surprising result of using three threads from the thread pool.

```
void Main()
{
    Wait();
}

public async void Wait()
{
    Print ("Wait() called. Calling GetAnswer()");
    var t = await GetAnswerAsync3();
    Print("Result of Wait(): " + t);
}

public Task<bool> GetAnswerAsync3()
{
    return Task.Run(() => {
            // Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Print("GetAnswerAsync3() called");
        return true;
    });
}

public void Print(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - " + message);
}
```

The result is:

```
Thread: 35 - Wait() called. Calling GetAnswer()
Thread: 51 - GetAnswerAsync3() called
Thread: 43 - Result of Wait(): True
```

Showing that there are three threads involved.

Now. If I add a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` to the Task returned by `GetAnswerAsync3` before it returns, the result is now only two threads in action! Maybe this could be because the threadpool re-uses a thread?

Why are three different threads in action here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `async` method is broken up into several pieces of work, which in this case are all scheduled to the thread pool. `await` designates a place where the `async` method may be "broken".

The first thread is the main thread, which is not part of the thread pool.

The second thread is one that is used to execute the delegate passed to `Task.Run`. This can be any thread on the thread pool.

The third thread is one that is used to pick up the execution of `Wait` after its `await`. This can also be any thread on the thread pool.

Conceptually, that's what happens. In reality, it's a bit more complex:

I think it's easier to explain with the `Thread.Sleep` first. In this case, `Wait` has been completely suspended by its `await` before the `Task.Run` completes. When the `Task.Run` completes, it executes its continuations, and the continuation of an `async` method has `ExecuteSynchronously` set ([described on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html)). So the same thread running `Thread.Sleep` actually continues executing `Wait` without yielding.

Your original code has a race condition: the `Task.Run` is very short so it will complete quickly. What you're seeing is that `Wait` checks the `Task` and sees it has not yet completed and suspends the `Wait` method. In the meantime, `Task.Run` completes and will schedule the remainder of `Wait` to the thread pool.

If you want to learn more about how `await` works with contexts, I recommend my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). You usually don't have to worry about the details like this.

Comment: That makes sense. Why does it change when the `Thread.Sleep()` is added?

Comment: Without the `Sleep`, there's a race condition where the second thread is still considered busy working when the continuation is scheduled onto a third thread. With the `Sleep`, the method is already suspended by the time the `Task` completes, so (as an optimization) the second thread will just execute the continuation directly.

Comment: If I, with the `Sleep` in place, add `ConfigureAwait(false)` to `GetAnswerAsync()`, why isn't there going to be three threads again?

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(false)` means that you don't care whether the current context is captured by `await` and used to continue the method. It does *not* mean "force this to be scheduled on the thread pool instead of executed directly".

Comment: Is there a way to force the continuation of `Wait` back on the main thread instead of the thread occupied by `Task.Run()`?

Comment: I cover this in my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) - again, please read it. By default, `await` will capture the current `SynchronizationContext` (unless it is `null`, in which case it uses the current `TaskScheduler`), and it will use that context to resume the `async` method. So if this is a UI app, it will return to the UI thread. Console apps don't have a SyncCtx, but [you can provide one of your own](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html).